# should apache default page show up when no sites are enabled?

Tags: apache2

When I do this :

```
sudo a2dissite
```

I get

```
Your choices are:
```

meaning all sites are disabled.

When I put my IP local network address in the browser, I get the default Apache page.

```
http://192.168.1.101/ (putting this in the browser address bar gets me the default apache page)
```

Stopping apache with

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

gives me the 'This site can’t be reached', so apache is serving that default page.

So, is it proper for the apache default page show up when no sites are enabled?

Followup : how would I make a different directory the default? I have a test.conf set up

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/myusername/websites/wp-test-site/site

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I thought that enabling that would make the default site folder /home/myusername/websites/wp-test-site/site, but it does not.

Yes Im restarting with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Add .htaccess file to the document root. 
Change the default file to be shown as follows

```
DirectoryIndex index.php default.html
```

Now put some index.php in document root directory.
Next you can point from index file where to point the user.